# How to remove an item from a linked list within 30 seconds after the addition of?

Tags: c++, list, data-structures, linked-list

How to remove an item from a linked list within 30 seconds after the addition of? Hava you any idea ? This question I was asked at the interview.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that I can achieve this on my box without overclocking and water-cooling.  Maybe you should add some more conditions?  Is the list supposed to autonomously remove items after they have 'lived' for 30 seconds, eg. by means of an internal thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say 'within' do you mean any time? Or upon 30 seconds elapsing. If you're trying to expire items then you need to put a timer somewhere.

You could create a kind of queue that moves items through at a fixed time (the expiration).

You could walk the queue continually, like a garbage collector, in which case the removal will be indeterminate.

Or you could put a timer on the item itself, started when you add the item to the queue, which signals the list when its time expires. The list could then remove the item.

Answer (score 7):

```
std::list<int> l;
l.push_back(42);
l.pop_back();
```

Unless you have an **incredibly** slow computer, this should finish in within the 30 second time limit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "within 30 seconds after the addition" but I see two possibilities:

1. You want to do this as fast as possible < 30 secs, in which case you can simply just add the element and then remove it:

   ```
   std::list<type> my_list;
   my_list.push_back(element);
   my_list.pop_back();
   ```
2. You want to do this close to 30 seconds as possible, in which case you can simply add the element, then remove it after 30 seconds:

   ```
   #include <unistd.h>

    // push back element here
   sleep(30);
    // pop back element here
   ```

Comment: What sleep function are you referring to?  I was not aware of a standard one in C++

Comment: @Attila It's a posix function, so it should be in all unix-like distributions... Here's the man page - http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to be able to measure time for this.  You could use std::time(NULL) and do a busy loop until the time required passed, but that seems inapropriate: fist of all, you are making the CPU work while you are waiting, second, you cannot do much meaningful tasks while you are waiting).

The next best thing is to use threads: you create a thread that will wait until the ellapsed time and remove the element from the list while the other does some meaningful work.  The C++03 standard does not define a common way of working with threads (so you need to look up the perticulars of the threading library you are using).  The C++11 standard does define its own memory model and provide threading library as part of the atnadard library (STL).

Answer (score 0):

I would use [signal](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) and [alarm](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm):

```
int popit();
signal(SIGALRM, popit);
std::list<int> l;
l.push_back(42);
alarm(30);
```

popit:

```
popit(){
   l.pop_back();
}
```

Comment: This is platform (*nix) specific